# Barra fixa no topo com informações (responsividade)

Tags: bootstrap

estou com dificuldade de montar um layout com bootstrap que tenha no topo do site uma barra simples com algumas informações. Esta barra deverá ser dividida para alocar as seguintes informações:

Do lado esquerdo:
Nome da empresa - (99) 99999-9999 - email@empresa.com.br

Do lado direito
serão colocados 4 ícones de redes sociais

(abaixo dessa barra do topo tem uma barra de menu que já esta funcionando)

O problema começa quando mudo os tamanhos das telas, simulando a responsividade, fica tudo bagunçado. Entendo que preciso trabalhar com media queries, porém não estou sabendo trabalhar direito com as colunas do bootstrap. Qual a melhor forma de resolver essa questão, podem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Para fazer algo simples assim, acho que você está complicando demais :). Veja este Fiddle com um conceito do que vc quer fazer de forma simples e deixando o Bootstrap de lado: https://jsfiddle.net/ms19kfem/

Comment: Acho que vai ter que fazer na mão mesmo, porque se usar o bootstrap ele quebra a linha quando a tela é pequena :/

Comment: interessante... vou verificar aqui como será melhor... mas é uma boa solução! eu andei tentando aqui e dá pra executar a tarefa com offset do bootstrap... mas agradeço! muito obrigado!